# swing JPanel paint method is responding but expecting paintComponents to respond while setting background image

Tags: swing, jpanel

I am setting a background image in JPanel with this

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel(){
            @Override
            public void paint(Graphics g) {
                super.paint(g);
                g.drawImage(ImageHelper.createResizedCopy(image, height, width, false), 0, 0, null);
            }

        };


        panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(height, width));
        panel.setOpaque(false);
        panel.add(new JLabel("SCIENCE FAIR"));
        panel.setBorder(new RoundedBorder(1,2,new Color(100, 200, 112)));

        return panel;
```

I was expecting paintComponents method to respond but somehow paintComponents is not responding but paint is doing the job for painting a background image in JPanel.
This JPanel is the child of another JPanel .
The Parent JPanel is using MigLayout and inside the parent JPanel, I am adding 4 different JPanels with different different background image.

Background image is done but on top of Background image , I am not able to add JLabel, so I doubt the paint method is the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're painting the entire component *after* the children are painted -- you're painting right over them, in other words. *Never* override `paint()` in a Swing component; override `paintComponent()` instead, and be sure to call `super.paintComponent()` *after* painting the background image.

Answer (score 1):

Also change this:

```
g.drawImage(ImageHelper.createResizedCopy(image, height, width, false), 0, 0, null);
```

To this:

```
g.drawImage(ImageHelper.createResizedCopy(image, height, width, false), 0, 0, this);
```

A `JPanel` is an `ImageObserver`, so you might as well supply it as the .. `ImageObserver`.

Comment: thanks for the comment but while calling this Panel, I have a Thread operation and if I pass "this", my UI thread operation is getting affected. So I avoided

Comment: @AbhishekChoudhary: If so, verify correct use of [Initial Threads](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).